# APIs to add a borders to a section of code in the VS Code editor using the VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a VS code extension where I have to differentiate a  certain parts of the code with borders like python code cells in VS Code.
I have tried out Decorations API but it is only can be use style part of text but I would to like to add border for the whole section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code.  The easy part is the border decoration:

```js
    const borderTopLeftRight = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        borderWidth: '2px 2px 0 2px',
        borderStyle: 'solid',   
        borderSpacing: '2px',
        borderColor: '#f00',
        isWholeLine: true,

        backgroundColor: 'rgba(253, 253, 254, 0.53)',
        rangeBehavior: vscode.DecorationRangeBehavior.OpenOpen
    }); 

    const borderBottomLeftRight = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        borderWidth: '0 2px 2px 2px',
        borderStyle: 'solid',           
        borderSpacing: '2px',
        borderColor: '#f00',
        isWholeLine: true,

        backgroundColor: 'rgba(253, 253, 254, 0.53)',
        rangeBehavior: vscode.DecorationRangeBehavior.OpenOpen
    });

    const borderLeftRight = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        borderWidth: '0 2px 0 2px',
        borderStyle: 'solid',           
        borderSpacing: '2px',
        borderColor: '#f00',
        isWholeLine: true,

        backgroundColor: 'rgba(253, 253, 254, 0.53)',
        rangeBehavior: vscode.DecorationRangeBehavior.OpenOpen
    });
    

    vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(borderTopLeftRight,  [new vscode.Range(2,0,2,0)]);
    vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(borderBottomLeftRight,  [new vscode.Range(6,0,6,0)]);
    vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(borderLeftRight,  [new vscode.Range(3,0,5,0)]);
    
    vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(editor => {
        vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(borderTopLeftRight, [new vscode.Range(2, 0, 2, 0)]);
        vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(borderBottomLeftRight, [new vscode.Range(6, 0, 6, 0)]);
        vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(borderLeftRight, [new vscode.Range(3, 0, 5, 0)]);
    });


    // may have to watch this too
    // vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection()
```

This draws a border on the top/left/right with one set of decorations for the first line of your desired range.  And then left/right with the in-between lines and finally bottom/left/right for the last line of your desired range of lines.

The trickier part is how you are going to determine the ranges to decorate - the code above just hard-codes a range but you will have to determine your ranges and loop through them applying the decorations.

[image: decorate a range of lines with a border]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a dedicated API to do this, but you can use [the text editor decoration API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) to do it by making empty text decorations and using CSS borders.

If you want an existing implementation to reference, take a look at [the code of the blockman extension](https://github.com/leodevbro/vscode-blockman/tree/main/src) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.